# call controller method from directive when I am using controller of directive also.

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive and now I want to send same data to other controller's methods and this controller is totally independent of this directive. this other controller is actually resides out the current directory.

How can I do this in angularjs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an angular service and inject in both the controllers. Update a variable in that service from controller 1 and retrieve in controller 2. Something like this -

```
myApp.factory('myFactory', function () {
    // declare and store the value in a local variable here
    var prop = '';

    return {
        getProperty: function () {
            return prop;
        },
        setProperty: function(value) {
            prop = value;
        }
    };
});

function Ctrl1($scope, myFactory) {
    myFactory.setProperty('myValue');
}

function Ctrl2($scope, myFactory) {
    val = myFactory.getProperty();
}
```

An angular service is a Singleton, so it maintains the state throughout the code.

Answer (score 1):

In angularjs there is an idea about directive scope.It lets you to use data for directive with 3 ways.

1) string @

2) biDirectional =

3) functional &

I think you have heard about these.This link maybe can help you.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#directive-definition-object